# Detect touch position in array of view (REACT NATIVE)

Tags: react-native

I am creating a planning application in react native and i couldn't handle the creation of a new view above a list of rendered views

I want to detect a user touch in map of views and show a view in the touch position, I tried to use

`<TouchableOpacity onPress={(evt)=>{this.setTopNewViewPostion(evt.nativeEvent.locationY}}`

but this was rendering the view for all slots that mean it is duplicated every time

Thanks

```
 handleClick (){  this.setState({newSlotVisible: true});} renderSlotsOfTab(tab, i){
    const ViewFlex = [1, 2, 3, 4];
  return (
      <TouchableOpacity
       onStartShouldSetResponder={() => true}
       onMoveShouldSetResponder={() => true}
       onResponderMove={()=>this.hideNewSlot()}
       ref={(ref) => i}
       tabLabel={tab}
       key={i}
       activeOpacity={1}
      >
  {
    ViewFlex.map((b , i)=>
      {
        return(
          <TouchableOpacity
            ref={i}
            removeClippedSubviews
            style={[styles.oneSlotView ,
              { flex: b }]}
            key={i}
            /** here get the touch position**/
            onPress={this.handleClick.bind(this, i)}

          >

            <View
              style={ styles.hoursIndicatorView}
            >
              <Text style={styles.textIndicatorTime}>00h00</Text>
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>)
      }
    )}
  {this.state.newSlotVisible?
    //the new view to render is this one
    this.renderNewView();
    :null}
</TouchableOpacity>
```

);
}

Comment: Could you post your entire component or ideally make a snack with it?